# Filtrar dominios de una lista de correos electrónicos - Python

Tags: python

Hola tengo una duda en el resultado de mi codigo, que tiene como objetivo primero filtrar los dominios de una lista de correos electronicos con el @, y luego filtrar los dominios repetidos y ponerlos en otra lista, pero el resultado son un monton de listas

```
correos=["correo1@gmail.com", 
           "correo2@hotmail.com", 
           "correo3@gmail.com", 
           "correo4@bing.io", 
           "correo@bing.io", 
           "correo6@yahoo.com", 
           "correo7@etc.edu"]

listadom= []
for l in correos:
    if l[l.find("@") : ] not in listadom:
        listadom.append(l[l.find("@") : ])
        print(listadom)
```

Y resulta en esto:

```
['@gmail.com']
['@gmail.com', '@hotmail.com']
['@gmail.com', '@hotmail.com', '@bing.io']
['@gmail.com', '@hotmail.com', '@bing.io', '@yahoo.com']
['@gmail.com', '@hotmail.com', '@bing.io', '@yahoo.com', '@etc.edu']
```

Solo quiero que se muestre como esta en la ultima fila, en que me estoy equivocation o como podria ser un codigo mejor, gracias de antemano

Comment: Estas imprimiendo en cada iteración. Cambia eso; imprime al terminar el `for`. Dentro del `for` solo tienes que ir seleccionado y agregando dominios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estabas imprimiendo cada vez que se ejecutaba el `for`, tenías que sacar el `print()` del bloque del `for`

```
correos=["correo1@gmail.com", 
       "correo2@hotmail.com", 
       "correo3@gmail.com", 
       "correo4@bing.io", 
       "correo@bing.io", 
       "correo6@yahoo.com", 
       "correo7@etc.edu"]

listadom= []
for l in correos:
    if l[l.find("@") : ] not in listadom:
        listadom.append(l[l.find("@") : ])
print(listadom)
```

Comment: muchas gracias, y losiento por la pregunta noob, recien aprendiendo